# How do I update ASP.NET MVC partial view asynchronously?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to asynchronously update a table of data based on the user's selection from a drop-down. Using stuff I've read [here](https://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/) and elsewhere, I've been trying to use a partial view to accomplish this. My code looks something like this:

Home.cshtml:

```
<body>
<div id="main-region">       
    <div class="mySelector">
        <label class="dropdown-label">Filter: </label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStatus, Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(MyEnum)),
       new { @id = "mySelector" })
    </div>
    <div id="myPartialView">
        @Html.Partial("_Summary", Model)
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#mySelector').change(function () {
        var newSelectionID = $(this).val();
        $('#myPartialView').load('@Url.Action("Filter", "Home")') //syntax for including newSelectionID?
    });

</script>
```

_Summary.cshtml is just a simple table.

HomeController.cs:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Filter(string statusID)
    {
      var modelData = mService.GetData(statusID);
        return PartialView("_Summary", model);
    }
```

I'm stuck on two things:

- I can't even seem to get this to hit my Filter method server-side.
- I'm not sure how to pass back the user-selected value.

I'm obviously missing something. Can anyone help me out? I'm using asp.net core.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You are trying to call `Filter` instead of `FilterOnStatus`

Comment: @Shyju thanks. mistake made when copying to SO. it's correct in my code. I edited it.

Comment: So what is the problem ? Is it making the ajax call when the dropdown selection is made ? Are you getting a 200 OK response for the call ? BTW, you are not passing the parameter value may be that is causing your server side code to crash and return a non 200 OK response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code might be crashing because you are not passing the `statusID` parameter to your method and i see you are using the parameter value to get the model data needed for the partial view. If the code crashes, the server will return a **500** Internal error status code in the response and the div (`myPartialView`) will not be updated with the content.

Since your action method is decorated with GET attribute, you may pass the value in querystring.

This should work

```
$(function() {

    $('#mySelector').change(function() {
        var v = $(this).val();
        $('#myPartialView').load('@Url.Action("FilterOnStatus", "Home")?statusID=' + v);
    });

});
```

Comment: Basically what I was going to post, note the updated OP using new method

Comment: Thanks for the response. This helped me. Just a stupid typo in the query string syntax on my part.